# Basic summation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm practicing Haskell, and writing a summation function that takes in two numbers (upper and lower limits) and does the summation.

ie, `summation 0 10` would return 55

I can get it mostly working, but having trouble figuring out how to get it using only two parameters.

Here is what I have so far:

```
summation :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
summation x y sum =
    if (y<x) then
        sum
    else
        summation x (y-1) (sum+y)
```

So this works fine, but I need to do `summation 0 10 0` to get it working properly. I'm not sure how I can get this working with only two parameters in Haskell.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You wrap it.

```
summation :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
summation x y = summation' x y 0

summation' :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
summation' x y sum =
    if (y<x) then
        sum
    else
        summation' x (y-1) (sum+y)
```

Comment: I don't get it. I _swear_ I tried this exact solution and it complained that there was `No instance for (Show (Integer -> Integer))` --- regardless, thank you.

Comment: @dc your problem would have been calling `show (summation 0)` or something similar. The problem is that summation is only applied to 1 argument, so it returns a function from Integer to Integer, which there is no instance of `Show` for. On the other hand `show (summation 0 10)` would work. You may have had the right solution but a peripheral problem caused you to think it was wrong. The code above never calls `show` so that couldn't have been the problem.

Comment: @Joel, thanks for the comment. I'm not sure that was the issue. I've never called `show` before, nor am I sure what exactly it does, as I'm quite new to Haskell. I must've mistyped something along the way.

Comment: @dc, You likely tried this or something like this, and did "summation' 0 10", which would give the same complaint as "summation 0" would, if for technically different reasons. :)

Answer (score 10):

### The quick answer:

One simple way would be to use the `sum` function from `Data.List`.

Then you could simply say:

```
summation x y = sum [x .. y]
```

This solution assumes that `x` is less than `y`, and you could fix this by saying:

```
summation x y = sum [min x y .. max x y]
```

---

### Defining `sum`:

Since you are learning Haskell, it might be important to know how `sum` works, instead of just knowing it exists.  For me, the biggest hurdle to get over initially was writing too many functions that already existed; especially since I didn't know how to write them effectively.

[Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) is a great help in this regard: it's a search engine that allows you to seach for Haskell functions.  It's a great thing for productivity, because you'll be able to spend time working on your problem, instead of producing poor rewrites of half of the prelude.  It's also great for learning, because there are links to the source code of most of the functions on [Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/).  The source code of the `Prelude` and other "fundamental" libraries such as `Data.List` is surprisingly accessible to a beginner, and will provide a lot of insight into how "the smart kids" do things.

The `:browse` command in GHCI is something that I found out about recently that I wish I'd discovered sooner.

Anyway, one way of defining `sum` is by using a fold:

```
sum xs y = foldl (+) 0 xs
```

Or the equivalent in ["pointless" style](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree):

```
sum = foldl (+) 0
```

I usually prefer the first formulation, but knowing how and why the second one works will help you a lot in your journey.

---

### Further Reading:

You'll notice that I used the function `foldl`.  This function "folds" an input list.  To "master" functional programming, knowing how to `fold` is both one of the most basic and important concepts.  A good resource to consult is the [page on folds](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Fold) from the [Haskell Wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/).

Comment: For reducing a list into a single item like with (+) you should always use the strict version foldl' because otherwise it builds a huge ((((1+2)+3)+4)+5)+6 style expression before doing any addition.

Comment: I actually just "stole" this definition from `Data.List`.  Thanks for the heads up.

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl' appears to be a good resource discussing the phenomena you're talking about.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it like Gauss did.

```
summation begin end
    | end < begin = summation end begin
    | otherwise   = n * (2*a + (n-1)*d) `div` 2
  where a = begin
        d = 1
        n = end - begin + 1
```

Code is a blatantly literal translation from http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.02.06/jo1.html (a little ways down that page: `S = n[2a + (n-1)d]/2`)

Comment: +1 for reminding us that formulas are just as good as algorithms.  The O(1) solution is right there.  I love it!  

It's probably not the best solution to give somebody trying to *learn to program*, though.

One nit: you could omit the multiplication by 1.

Comment: This solution would actually be `O(n log n log log n)` for large inputs (where n is the number of bits in the input), doing multiplication three times, and assuming "/2" is implemented as a binary shift. The repeated addition would be `O(n 2^n)`, since each addition is O(n) and, for inputs with n bits, there must be roughly 2^n additions performed. Complexities for addition/multiplication are [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations).

Comment: Using that formula with n = 10^7 works out to (I think) 343x10^7 operations.  At 3 GHz and one operation per cycle this would take 1.143 seconds.  

This is unrealisticly fast for a number of reasons, but I still (unfortunately?) have never done any work where multiplication was the bottleneck.

Thanks for the link, though... now I'm going to spend all day on Wikipedia ;)

Comment: Hier a good link:http://betterexplained.com/articles/techniques-for-adding-the-numbers-1-to-100/